# Dependency Injection in BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, performance, dependency-injection, singleton, android-broadcastreceiver

Is it a good practice to inject a Singleton to a BroadcastReceiver?

More specifically lets assume I have singleton like the following:

```
@Singleton
public class UnitProvider {

    private boolean mIsUsingCelsius = false;

    protected SharedPreferences mSharedPrefs;

    @Inject
    public UnitProvider(SharedPreferences sharedPrefs) {
        mSharedPrefs = sharedPrefs;
        mIsUsingCelsius = isUsingCelsiusPref(Locale.getDefault()); 
     }

    public void refreshCelsius() {

        if (!mSharedPrefs.contains(SharedPreferencesConstants.SP_KEY_USE_CELSIUS)) {
            mIsUsingCelsius = isUsingCelsiusBasedOnLocale(Locale.getDefault());
        } 
    }
}
```

And there is a broadcast receiver:

```
public class DummyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Inject protected UnitProvider mUnitProvider;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        DependencyInjectionService.inject(this);
        mUnitProvider.refreshCelsius();
    }
}
```

Actually it works but I am not sure about the performance and possible memory leak that situation may cause. Is there any idea about performance and possible lags that injection may cause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be OK.  A BroadcastReceiver instance is only alive for as long as it takes it to return from onReceive.  It will be eligible for garbage collection after that as long as you didn't do something silly like hold a reference to it.

Also, you can't really "leak" a singleton object because basically they are expected to last forever!